# JAVA - Add ! and ? to regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have this sentenceparser with keyword regex pattern:
`[^.]*\b(keywords)\b[^.]*[.]`
And it works well apart from it will not end sentences to ! and ? symbols, only to dots. So how do I modify it? I tried `"[^.]*\\b(" + keywords + ")\\b[^.]*[.!?]"` and that didnt work.

Comment: You should account for these chars in other parts of the regex, too, `"[^.!?]*\\b(" + word_re + ")\\b[^.!?]*[.!?]"`

Comment: That did the thing, thanks! @WiktorStribiżew